# Place buttons over complex shapes on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a beginner with Android.  I have this shape located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhSR6.png that I am trying to get each section to be a button(24 buttons).  I have investigated all over the web and cannot find a way to do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `View`, draw this image, and watch for clicks in each region.